# Reponsive Div Float and Height Adjust

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

Following is my fiddle in which I am trying to float div to left and arrange the divs WRT to the height e.g. if 3 divs in a row are not of equal heights then the next three divs should adjust accordingly as per the height of the previous upper 3 divs AND RESPONSIVE on squeeze the divs can easily go to next line.

**Instead of images I want my divs to be arranged like** http://www.kaspervanvliet.nl/index.html

**Another Example** http://januarycreative.com/portfolio/

I hope following may explains it all:

[image]

**JSFIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/StfUk/ (Increase the width of diplay window)

```
/* *********************************************************************************************************************
 * Main container for all
 */
.onepcssgrid-1000, .onepcssgrid-1200 {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 0 0 1%; /* THAT'S THE NAME ;) */
}

.onepcssgrid-1200 {
    max-width: 100%;
}

.onepcssgrid-1000 {
    max-width: 1020px;
}

.onerow {
    clear: both;
    padding: 0 10px;
}

/* *********************************************************************************************************************
 * Common columns definitions
 */
.col1, .col2, .col3, .col4, .col5, .col6, .col7, .col8, .col9, .col10, .col11, .col12 {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 3% 0 0;
}

.col1.last, .col2.last, .col3.last, .col4.last, .col5.last, .col6.last, .col7.last, .col8.last, .col9.last, .col10.last, .col11.last, .col12 {
    margin: 0;
}

.col1 { width: 5.5%; }
.col2 { width: 14%; }
.col3 { width: 22.5%; }
.col4 { width: 31%; }
.col5 { width: 39.5%; }
.col6 { width: 48%; }
.col7 { width: 56.5%; }
.col8 { width: 65%; }
.col9 { width: 73.5%; }
.col10 { width: 82%; }
.col11 { width: 90.5%; }
.col12 { width: 99%; margin: 0; }

.col1 img, .col2 img, .col3 img, .col4 img, .col5 img, .col6 img, .col7 img, .col8 img, .col9 img, .col10 img, .col11 img, .col12 img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
}

/* *********************************************************************************************************************
 * Disable padding left/right 10px if I'm 1024 or gibber - correct percentage math
 */
@media all and (min-width: 1024px) {
    .onepcssgrid-1000 {
        max-width: 1000px;
    }

    .onepcssgrid-1000 .onerow {
        padding: 0;
    }
}

/* *********************************************************************************************************************
 * Small devices
 */
@media all and (max-width: 768px) {
    .onerow {
    }

    .col1, .col2, .col3, .col4, .col5, .col6, .col7, .col8, .col9, .col10, .col11 {
        float: none;
        width: 99%;
    }
}
```

Comment: As you can easily see using a DOM inspector, the first page you mentioned has the elements that appear in the columns grouped together in container DIVs. And the second one uses [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) to get the effect done using JavaScript.

Comment: @CBroe can you please apply it here JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/StfUk/ (Increase the width of fiddle's display window to override the breakpoint)

Answer (score 0):

well I looked at the example and its quiet easy. there are three divs as container and the images (in your case divs) are nested in these divs just have to have top and bottom margin defined:

css:

```
.parent{
padding:10px;
float:left;
width:300px;
}

.item{
margin:20px 0px;
display:block;
width:300px;
}
```

html:

```
<div style="text-align:center">
    <div style="display:inline-block">
        <div class="parent">
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="parent">
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="parent">
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

divs with class **item** are those divs you want.

Comment: See if you can apply on http://jsfiddle.net/StfUk/1/ . Note increase the width of the display window for div separation.